# Using Taylor series to prove $\sqrt{1+xa}\approx(1+x)\sqrt{\frac{a}{2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Is it true that

> $\sqrt{1+xa}\approx(1+x)\sqrt{\frac{a}{2}}$ for a$\gg$1

I took $x=1$, then the above becomes $\sqrt{1+a}\approx\sqrt{2a}$ which is untrue for very large $a$. But it is asked to prove the above by using Taylor's Series.

Comment: What limit are you considering? Large $a \to \infty$, fixed $x$? In that case the result is false.

Comment: Here $a$ is fixed, and it is a function of $x$.

Comment: So what is the point you want to take the Taylor series at? "$\approx$" only makes sense if some variable is assumed to approach some value.

Comment: No, it doesn't appear to be true,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression in the OP is false.  Simply let $x=0$; certainly $\sqrt{1+a\cdot 0}=1$ is not asymptotically $(1+0)\sqrt{a/2}=\sqrt{a/2}$.

For $x>0$ and fixed, we have for $a\to \infty$

$$\sqrt{1+ax}=\sqrt{ax}\sqrt{1+\frac1{ax}}\sim \sqrt{ax}\left(1+\frac{1}{2ax}\right)$$